# Registering a schema in schema registry using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-schema-registry

I implemented Schema Registry using spring boot. I can see that its up and running as I try to get a schema by ID using below URL in PostMan it returns proper expected response.

URL: http://localhost:8999/schemas/101
Response:  Schema not found: Could not find schema by ID: 101

But the problem is with registering the schema. I tried multiple multiple options and combinations both GET and POST side and also searched. Nothing seem to work.

Comment: Please show how you registered the schema and what the response was once you did. Do you actually have 101 schemas? Otherwise, the first schema is only ID 1

Comment: Hi, 101 was just an example it was not working with 1 as well earlier. Anyway it got resolved as I posted in the answer. My understanding Schema Registry is implemented differently Confluent vs Spring boot.  I was looking at Confluent documentation earlier. End points were different.

Answer (score 0):

This got resolved. I got to know that we can register a schema by posting below fields over end-point "/" in JSON format.

http://localhost:8999/
Post with body in JSON format with something like below.

```
{
 "subject":"Employee",
  "format":"avro",
  "definition":" -- your schema def --"
}
```